# Mudar vertices de um plano fazendo rotação

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, rotação

Tenho um plano na tela e quero rotacionar ele em 5 graus, sem usar o `glRotate`, tenho o código:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 500
#define WIDTH 500
#define POINTS 5

#define TRANSLATE 5
#define ROTATION 5.0
#define SCALE_M 0.5
#define SCALE_P 1.5

void display();
void specialKeys();

typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} Dot;

Dot dots[5];
int i, translate = 0, rotate = 0, scale = 0;
char typeRotate = '\0';

Dot point(float x, float y, float z) {
  Dot p;
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  p.z = z;

  return p;
}

void createPoints() {
  dots[0] = point(00, 00, 00);
  dots[1] = point(20, 00, 00);
  dots[2] = point(20, 20, 00);
  dots[3] = point(00, 20, 00);
}

void drawDot(float x, float y, float z) { glVertex3f(x / 30, y / 30, z / 30); }

void display() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();

  for (i = 0; i < POINTS; i++) {
    dots[i].x = (dots[i].x * cos(-ROTATION)) - (dots[i].y * sin(-ROTATION));
    dots[i].y = (dots[i].x * sin(-ROTATION)) + (dots[i].y * cos(-ROTATION));
  }

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  for (i = 0; i < POINTS; i++)
    drawDot(dots[i].x, dots[i].y, dots[i].z);

  glEnd();

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  createPoints();
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  glutInitWindowPosition(150, 150);
  glutCreateWindow("Exercicio Lista");
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

A parte na qual tento rotacionar o plano é:

```
for (i = 0; i < POINTS; i++) {
    dots[i].x = (dots[i].x * cos(-ROTATION)) - (dots[i].y * sin(-ROTATION));
    dots[i].y = (dots[i].x * sin(-ROTATION)) + (dots[i].y * cos(-ROTATION));
}
```

Onde tento rotacionar os pontos seguindo uma formula que vi em [Transformações Geometricas USP](http://www.lcad.icmc.usp.br/~rosane/CG/TransfGeomAndersonIcaro.pdf). Mas o resultado não foi uma rotação em 5 graus no eixo Z, vocês podem ver ao executar o arquivo.

P.S.: Compilação é:

```
gcc -o lista lista.c -lm -lglut -lGL -lGLU && ./lista
```

Espero que ajudem a descobrir o erro no cálculo, não tentei fazer com as matrizes do PDF pois não entendi.

Comment: Dependendo do que você for fazer, dá pra otimizar absurdos com tabelas pré calculadas. Se for sempre de um em um grau, você pode já fazer um loop que calcula um vetor `seno[angulo] = sin( angulo / 360 * 2 * M_PI );` ai na fórmula já usa `( dots[i].x * seno[ROTATION] )`. Para valores menores que zero ou maiores que 360 basta usar módulo. Lembre-se ainda que o seno é igual o cosseno, só precisa deslocar 90 graus.

Comment: Realmente, no caso era só um exercício simples por isso não fiz mais elaborado, mas dessa maneira ficaria ótimo pra um trabalho que tenho, obrigado :) Ainda estou reajustando a formula, pois além de rotacionar está diminuindo a escala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As funções trigonométricas como `sin` e `cos` não trabalham com **graus de arco** (de 0 a 360) e sim com **radianos**.

Um **radiano** equivale a uma projeção do raio na circunferência:

[image: proporção de um radiano em relação à circunferência]

A volta toda equivale a 2 * PI, que é mais ou menos `6,28318530717958647692528676656`.

Então, em vez de usar algo como

```
sin( ROTATION )
```

Você precisa de

```
sin( ROTATION / 360 * 2 * M_PI )
```

Basta adaptar ao seu caso. A constante `M_PI` é padrão da `math.h`, ajuste se necessário.

<sub><sup>Imagem tirada de: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-radian-and-vs-degree/</sup></sub>

Comment: Obrigado, nunca iria pensar nisso, funcionou!

Comment: Note que praticamente tudo de trigonometria costuma ser em radianos nas linguagens em geral. Raramente algo usa grau de arco. Em linguagens ou bibliotecas mais especializadas costuma ter opção, mas no dia a dia é tudo radiano.