# Função arco tangente em C#

Tags: c#, .net, funções, matemática

Fiz o seguinte calculo na calculadora:

```
arctg(50/10) = 78,69°
```

Porém, ao fazer no código, usando a função `Math.Atan`, o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: Codigo]

Tem algum outro jeito de fazer o cálculo do Arco Tangente ?

Comment: Raphael, da uma olhadinha na documentação https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.math.atan(v=vs.110).aspx lá mostra que a função retorna o Angulo da tangente e não o arco, não me recordo bem sobre trigonometria, mas acredito que sejam coisas distintas.
E se você ver o exemplo, nele tem como calcular o arco da tangente.

Comment: @PabloVargas, são a mesma coisa, basicamente. O ângulo retornado é o referente ao arco em questão. O problema mesmo era a disparidade das unidades, como o bigown respondeu. Basta converter de radiano para graus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Math_Atan_System_Double_) diz que a entrada do método deve ser em radianos e você está usando graus. Tem que converter radiano para grau antes. A calculadora já está em graus, por isso deu certo.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(Atan(5) * 180 / PI);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZQ9TtM). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KgGO5r). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/AtanDegreeToRadin.cs).

Talvez queira criar funções para fazer a conversão:

```
public static class MathUtil {
    public static double DegreeToRadian(double angle) => PI * angle / 180.0;
    public static double RadianToDegree(double angle) => angle * (180.0 / PI);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BRXXyN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRapZG). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/ConversionDegreeToRadin.cs).

[Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168067/101).

Comment: Faltava essa conversão de radiano para graus. Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Ainda precisa pegar o resultado da operação (`Math.Atan`) e ***multiplicar*** pela ***divisão*** de **180** e a constante `PI`, ***exemplo***, para obter o valor em *Graus*:

```
int t = 50;
int p = 10;
double r = t / p;

var resultado = Math.Atan(r);
resultado = resultado * (180 / Math.PI);

System.Console.WriteLine(resultado);
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

---

Saída:

```
78,6900675259798
```

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/QAFHgE)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Método Math.Atan (Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.math.atan(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Cálculos matemáticos em C# - Classe Math](http://cbsa.com.br/post/calculos-matematicos-c-sharp-classe-math.aspx)
- [C# - Why is Math.Atan(1) != anything near 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564207/c-sharp-why-is-math-atan1-anything-near-45)